# I cannot install python-tk on python2.7

Tags: apt, python, dns, python-2.7

I am an Ubuntu Mate 16.04 user. I want to run [this program](https://github.com/dumyy/handpose). I have to use python2.7 to run the program. And I enter

```
python2 train_and_test.py
```

on the terminal. Then, an error was displayed.

> ImportError: No module named _tkinter, please install the python-tk package

So I have tried to install python-tk. I entered

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Installing was succeed. Next, I entered

```
sudo apt-get -y install python-tk
```

But installing was failed.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  tix python-tk-dbg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-tk
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 283 not upgraded.
Need to get 26.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 95.2 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 python-tk amd64 2.7.12-1~16.04
Something wicked happened resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-stdlib-extensions/python-tk_2.7.12-1~16.04_amd64.deb
Something wicked happened resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I have updated `apt-get`. How should I install `python-tk`?

Comment: Appears to be a DNS issue. does dmesg |grep NXDOMAIN produce anything? I found I needed to install libnss-resolve on a standard Ubuntu 18.04 to handle certain situations after a fallback to UDP.

Comment: I enter "dmesg |grep NXDOMAIN" on the terminal. But Nothing is displayed.

Comment: Do you mean I should install libnss-resolve?

Comment: If your /etc/nsswitch.conf hosts line does not have "resolve [!UNAVAIL=return]" just before dns, better install it.

Comment: Thank you. My /etc/nsswitch.conf hosts is "hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns".

Comment: I have tried to install libnss-resolve by typing "sudo apt-get install libnss-resolve". But the installing failed and "E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?" has been displayed.

Comment: I assumed youi have already run the apt-get update, since you got the python3. Try the --fix-broken I guess, but if dns is broken, it's usually temporarily. Try a reboot, and first think do the libnss-resolve install.  If still a problem, just edit the /etc/nsswitch.conf file directly -- here's mine, with the addition: hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns myhostname